# App problem loading page

Tags: apt

I am using firefox 28.0 and whenever I try to get an app from the software centre by clicking the software centre button it tells me this: Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (apt) isn't associated with any program.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are running an OS  other than Ubuntu.Please run the firefox browser in an Ubuntu machine and then click on the apt link.

Answer (score 0):

click "choose"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpECp.png

navigate to /usr/bin/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ME7N.png

Choose "software-center"

Comment: I don't have a software center